# Child widget packing in Gtk::Grid

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm

I have a **Gtk::Grid** of 3x3.

Row 1 has Menubar, row 2 has Toolbar and row 3 has a **Gtk::Notebook** widget.

When I try to add a new page(s) in the Gtk::Notebook widget, it does not fill up the area completely. It looks like this :

[image]

The Gtk::Notebook has a **Gtk::ScrolledWindow** and a **Gtk::TextView** as child widgets.

What can I do to pack the Gtk::Notebook widget to fill the remaining space to it's bottom and right side ?

In **Glade** there's a property under **"Widget spacing"** named **"Alignment"** and it's **Horizontal and Vertical** values set to Fill does the job.

[image]

Is there some function to do that in code only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working for now. Maybe it's not the best method, but it works.

After adding **Gtk::Notebook** to **Gtk::Grid**, call these two functions :

```
    /* Fill up the extra space avialable */
    m_pNotebook->set_hexpand(true);
    m_pNotebook->set_vexpand(true);
```